# How to fix "Failed to resolve: org.webrtc:google-webrtc"?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, webrtc, webrtc-android

I build an android webrtc app but when adding webrtc to the android studio project (implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'), I get this error : **Failed to resolve: org.webrtc:google-webrtc**

How to add webrtc to an android app ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently it seems we are forced to keep jcenter, a deprecated repository, to install this package. Jcenter remain readonly and is not removed for now.

For production you could considere making your own build.

```
// root build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
```

you can check this [issue](https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc/issues/543) from twillio

Comment: note that the package itself has been deprecated and not received security fixes (with one exception) since early https://groups.google.com/g/discuss-webrtc/c/Ozvbd0p7Q1Y/m/M4WN2cRKCwAJ?

Answer (score 3):

//*In the settings.gradle file*

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    //add jcenter()
    jcenter()
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

//Android => App => build.gradle

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take the step:

```
implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0+'
```

and Replace in code:

```
implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            ..
            maven { url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexgreench/google-webrtc/master" }
        }
 }

 dependencies {
     ..
     implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.30039@aar'
 }
```

Temporary solution
:)

Answer (score -1):

Try it with on maven central. I think this is the latest build based on the published date.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webrtc/google-webrtc/1.0.32006

In app build.gradle:

```
implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006'
```

In project build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```